# how do i use a scanner to read a file object

Tags: java

like the question how would I use a file object taken from the File class
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html

and use a scanner object wrapped around this to read the file,
then say a example like this is contained in the file,
Student{name=Jill Gall,age=21,gpa=2.98}
separate it into fields, skip next step as I just have to call the setters here, and then set the values
I then to save the fields as a Student Object and then save those in a array that I can return?

I'm not really looking for a solution to the entire problem here I'm just wondering as to what the syntax is for calling a scanner object wrapped around a File object to read it, I can use substring to grab the fields to separate and save them onto the new fields, and I'm pretty sure I can just use a for loop to load these onto a array that i can return, the only reason I listed out the entire problem for you guys is so I can give you guys the most details about the task as I can give here

right now my best attempt is this

```
Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);
n.commandgoeshere?(filename);
```

how would I get the scanner to output the data so that i can take a substring and do the stuff i need to do above?

Comment: You can simply use the [nextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide an input stream in the constructor of the scanner, atm you are providing the system input stream (from the console) to the scanner. I think something like this is what you are looking for:

```
    File file = new File("");

    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String nextLine = scanner.nextLine();
            // or use regex ?
            String extractedPattern = scanner.next("some pattern");
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```